# images won't display in IE9

Tags: html, browser

The image code below works fine in Mozilla, Chrome and Safari but doesn't display in IE9.

It is saved as an image in photoshop for websites and I specified the height and width.

When I write it like this without the slash before "D:"

```
<img src="D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />
```

it works in IE but then it doesn't display in Mozilla.

```
<img src="/D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />
```

this code works fine in all browsers apart from IE

```
<img src="D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />
```

this one works fine in all apart from Mozilla

this is the whole div and there is not css style yet.

```
<section class="container">

     <div class="image_carousel">
     <div id="foo2">
    <img src="/D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />

     </div>
     </article>

</section>
```

Do you think it is the extension problem and I should save the image as GIF not jpg. ?

and if I wanted to create separate code for IE would it work if I make comments like these below in my html file? and put the image code inside those comments for IE9?

```
             <!--[if IE]>

            <![endif]-->
```

Comment: Imsorry it didnt show properly     <img src="/D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" /> this code works fine in all browsers apart from IE      and when I remove dash line before D: it works in all apart from Mozilla

Comment: Try `file://D:/obrazki/game.jpg` but if your HTML file is in the same directory, you can simply use `game.jpg`

Comment: I tried this one as well but it didn't help

Comment: Sorry I mean `file:///D:/obrazki/game.jpg` - if that doesn't work either, linking to local paths may be restricted for security reasons. Then you would have to have the image in the same directory your HTML file is in (or a sub-directory) and use a relative path, like `game.jpg`

Comment: If you specify a physical path on your computer, you are the only one who will ever be able to see the images. Why do you need it to be compatible with more than the web browser that you normally use?

Comment: It did solve it. thank you. it was so easy

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the image call be:

```
<img src="/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />
```

?

Or better yet:

```
<img src="/obrazki/images/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />
```

Where /obrazki would be where you have the pages/scripts to "call" your images..

Answer (score 0):

**What about linking to the image on a relative path:**

```
<img src="./link/to/image.jpg"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

ok, lets do an old and dirty solution...serve up the images for non-ie(s), then serve up the images for ie(s) via conditional comments. (sidenote: there's a few ways to do this, like using a background-image on a wrapper element around the image, but since you are relying on img elements, i'll stick to that method. so

```
  
<section class="container">  
  <article>  
    <div class="image_carousel">  
      <div id="foo2">  
        <img src="/D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" />  
        <!--[if lte IE 9]><img src="D:/obrazki/game.jpg" alt="game" width="1100" height="619" /><![endif]-->  
      </div>  
    </div>  
  </article>  
</section>
```

that should work...in theory. you may have fouc or positioning issues, though i doubt the fouc...it's hard to tell without seeing it live, with the rest of the document.